# How to code a HTML5 game with distinct game states

Tags: javascript, html, game-engine

I am new to HTML5 game development and I am trying to use the Quintus engine due to its lightweight and modular characteristics. I am thinking of creating a simple game that has multiple 'states', consisting of the following:

- Welcome/loading screen
- User config screen (e.g. choosing gender, hair colour etc)
- Game main menu (buttons to restart game, help etc)
- Actual play
- etc etc

I am confused on how I would go about dividing and structuring these states. I have a feeling stages and scenes (in Quintus) have something to do with this but I can't seem to pinpoint how to actually use them for this purpose.

http://html5quintus.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to use a state machine for that.  [Here's an excellent article](http://codeincomplete.com/posts/2013/5/19/javascript_gauntlet_logic/) on how this guy structured his game code, and [used a Finite State Machine](https://github.com/jakesgordon/javascript-state-machine) to handle state and transitioning between states.
The rest of his articles are definitely worth the read, particularly if you're new to javascript game development.

With regard more specifically to Quintus,  while I haven't used it, the overview gives a decent idea of how to switch between scenes/screens.

Basically, you just define your stages using `Q.scene('yourScene',function(stage) {})`, which can contain anything you like, such as a game play screen or menu,  then call `Q.stageScene("yourSceneLevelMenuEtc");` to switch to that state.

Answer (score 2):

For the user-config portion of your question, `Q.state` may come in handy.  From the docs:

> Quintus (v0.0.4 and up) provides a mechanism for tracking global game
>   state - be it number of lives remaining, score or inventory. This
>   comes in the form of the `Q.state` object (an instance of `Q.GameState`).

Look in the "Game State" section in this page: http://www.html5quintus.com/guide/core.md

Good luck!